# Replacing datetime values using for loop pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a df look like below, but much bigger. There are some incorrect dates under the column of lastDate, and they are only incorrect if there is something in correctDate column, right next to them.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(
            {"lastDate":['2016-3-27', '2016-4-11', '2016-3-27', '2016-3-27', '2016-5-25', '2016-5-31'],
             "fixedDate":['2016-1-3', '', '2016-1-18', '2016-4-5', '2016-2-27', ''],
             "analyst":['John Doe', 'Brad', 'John', 'Frank', 'Claud', 'John Doe']
            })
```

[image]

[image]
First one is what I have and the second one is what I'd like to have after the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert these columns to datetime dtypes:

```
for col in ['fixedDate', 'lastDate']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

Then you could use

```
mask = pd.notnull(df['fixedDate'])
df.loc[mask, 'lastDate'] = df['fixedDate']
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {"lastDate":['2016-3-27', '2016-4-11', '2016-3-27', '2016-3-27', '2016-5-25', '2016-5-31'], "fixedDate":['2016-1-3', '', '2016-1-18', '2016-4-5', '2016-2-27', ''], "analyst":['John Doe', 'Brad', 'John', 'Frank', 'Claud', 'John Doe'] })

for col in ['fixedDate', 'lastDate']:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

mask = pd.notnull(df['fixedDate'])
df.loc[mask, 'lastDate'] = df['fixedDate']
print(df)
```

yields

```
    analyst  fixedDate   lastDate
0  John Doe 2016-01-03 2016-01-03
1      Brad        NaT 2016-04-11
2      John 2016-01-18 2016-01-18
3     Frank 2016-04-05 2016-04-05
4     Claud 2016-02-27 2016-02-27
5  John Doe        NaT 2016-05-31
```

Comment: When I applied the mask to my real dataset, it made all the lastDate with null fixedDate as null as well. It didn't happened to the sample df. Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: I had written that converting the date-strings to actual dates was not strictly necessary but now I realize that isn't true. `pd.notnull([''])` equals `np.array([ True])` so the `mask` would be True where the `fixedDate` is an empty string. That would cause `df.loc[mask, 'lastDate'] = df['fixedDate']` to overwrite the `lastDate` even when the `fixedDate` is an empty string. That might explain the behavior you are seeing, assuming you did not convert the date-strings to `datetime64`s using `pd.to_datetime`.